# How is splash damage applied?

Tags: overwatch

In some games targets will take the base damage of an ability plus the splash damage the ability does, and other games, the primary target only takes the base damage, and the other targets in the AOE range take the splash damage. How does splash damage work in Overwatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spent some quality time with Pharah in the Practice Range, and it looks like the primary target will take the base damage and secondary targets will take splash, falling off with distance.